# HttpWebRequest simulating the request from firebug always failed

Tags: webrequest

I got an eccentric problem. I am trying to automate visiting a web site by using WebRequest and WebClient. I have observed all the post request header key-value pairs and posted data string in Firebug(request Header and Post tab). Then I simulated such request with WebRequest and put all the header parameter and posted data there. However when I do GetResponse() from this request instance, I always got an error page back that says some sessionID is short of.

Actually I have taken care to put previously(first step to open the Logon page) responded session cookie in the Header's cookie field for the request. And I can get the correct response back by simulating requesting the logon page(the 1st page), but cannot get through this authentication page. My post data is like userid=John&password=123456789&domain=highmark.And the authentication page request that carried out by browser succeeds every time.

Am I missing something in the request that may not be shown by firebug.If yes, can you give me some recommendation for the tools that may examine the entire request sent by browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. The problem is I set the httpWebRequest instance's AllowAutoRedirect=true. Thus the effect is when I got the first response from the server, the httpWebRequest would continually to make another request asking for a different url that is replied in the response header's Location field.

The defect of HttpWebRequest class is when it is getting redirected, it does not include the Set-Cookies(Response's Header Field)'s cookies in the next request header, thus the server would deny such page request and may redirect again to another different page.

And the httpWebRequest.GetResponse() method only return the last responsed page back under the setting AllowAutoRedirect=true. And I got the totally different response than I expected.

Also in this solving process, I need to thank to a distinguish Http Traffic examining tool:**IEInspector Http Analyzer**(http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/). The great feature of this tool is it can examine not only the http traffic from browser but also **what your process's httpWebRequest made**. And also it can display in text format the raw stream of those request and response. Although it is a commercial software, you can try it for 15 days. I am quite happy with what it tells me(in well-formed details) and I like to buy it as well.